# Is there a way to get pages visited by each user to a report?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

In google analytics `User Explorer` table, it shows data related to each user( or client id) as follows. 
[image]

After clicking on one of client id, it shows individual session details of that user( I'm interested in pages visited by each user). Is there a way to get those page visit data to a report? Or any method that can get those data via google analytics report API.

For example, I want to generate a report (either using google analytics or using my code using report API) as follows.

```
--------------------------------
client Id | pages visited       | 
--------------------------------
125       | /testpage, testpage2|
258       | testpage4,testpage5 |
...
---------------------------------
```

Comment: Is client id a custom dimension you have added?

Comment: No, google generate client id for each user, in my case I enabled user id feature and I'm sending user id to analytics.

Comment: Google Analytics does not expose clientId/userId via the API (and in the GUI only via in the user explorer report), so you'd need to add it yourself as a custom dimension to use it in an API query. Or if you have a GA 360 account then the BigQuery export schema includes the clientid.

Comment: If you have the client ID as custom Dimension, you can actually get the report via Big Query :)

Comment: Did you managed to solve the problem? This is exactly what I am trying now. I am using R to fetch GA data. But I am stuck at that point. I have problem with custom dimensions now. Was creating custom dimension 'clientId' work for you?

Answer (score 2):

> [Client ID](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#cid) anonymously identifies a particular user, device, or browser instance.

The value of client id is not available via the Google Analytics API.  Here is a list of the [dimensions and metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets) currently available.    Nor can you use it in the Google analytics website the only report it works on is the one you are currently using  "User Explorer" and its very limited to what you can do with that.

The only option you have would be to create a custom dimension and store the client id in that then you would be able to use your custom dimension in both reports and the API.

Comment: thank you for the answer. But when we create a custom dimension is there a way to track page visits by the user as in user explorer.

Comment: No the data has to be recorded when its  sent to Google.  Your going to have to add the custom dimension to the snippet on your website.